# XNA/MonoGame Viewport how to use it

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, monogame

Well I've read different articles and questions on stackoverflow. But everyone suggests to use camera with viewport. Why just don't move viewport itself? AFAIK from SFML example things outside viewport won't be drawed. But with your implemented camera you have to control which things should be drawn. Isn't it better just to control viewport instead of  camera?

Comment: I think now I understand how it works. Viewport limits things to be shown. Everything outside of it won't be shown. If we move viewport we will just move it relative to our window but same thing will be drawn. So, in most cases we don't need to work with viewport. Just moving things we want to draw with transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, Viewport methods are limited to what the viewing perspective of the user is. If you refer to "Viewport" you can ensure that the boundary will be directly within that range.

If you have an image that you are rendering to the screen, calling

```
Viewport.Width
```

will put your image directly outside of the viewing perspective.

You have to then do

```
Viewport.Width - myPicture.Width
```

for it to be viewable within the set boundaries.